# data not inserted in database in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm quite new to codeigniter. Currently i'm trying to insert data to my local database from input fields from form. There's no error that popped out but the data that was entered was not showing on my database. I've been reviewing my admin-index file, admin(controller) file and admin_model file. But the code is pretty understandable. Can't find the error. If database connection was the issue, I'm certain that it's successfully connected since I can log in  (especially with different usertypes). Below are my codes. Thanks for anyone who could share an idea :)

**admin.php(controller)**

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->model('Admin_model');
    }

    public function add()
    {
        $newData = array(
            'fname'     =>$this->input->post('firstName'),
            'lname'     =>$this->input->post('lastName'),
            'uname'     =>$this->input->post('userName'),
            'pword'     =>$this->input->post('passWord'),
            'utype'     =>$this->input->post('userType')
        );
        $this->load->model('Admin_model');
        $this->Admin_model->add_user($newData);   
    }
}
```

**admin_model.php**

```
<?php 


class Admin_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {   
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function add_user($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('tblaccount', $data);

        //echo($newData);
    }

}
```

**admin-index.php**

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/add" method="POST">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label> Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="userName" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="passWord" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>UserType</label>
    <input type="text" name="userType" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: from where you are sending data? try to fetch data from post with this $this->input->post(); than insert it.

Comment: i had used that code of line in my admin.php(controller) under add() function.As you can see, The action value of my html form = action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/add", calling admin class, add() function from my controller admin.php.

Comment: hi i think problem is here $this->Admin_model->add_user($newData);    call like this $this->admin_model->add_user($newData);

Comment: Umefarooq is correct. When you name your model use capitols. When you use it in code, do not capitalize the model name

Comment: Oh is that so. Well it worked now. I think my model is recognized even if its called capitalize, the issue was not in the functions at all ("model/controller"). method="post" was not recognized because it was put under div tag, where it should be on the form. But hey thanks for sharing idea. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I think i got it now. i just transfered the action="admin/add" method="POST" line of code from div tag to form tag. It worked!!!. At first I observed the behavior of my POST method in my html form. It's kinda strange cause it's acting like a GET method(user inputs are displayed in url). Then I initially conculed that maybe the method="POST" was not recognized.

Here is my final code on my html form:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/add" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('firstName'); ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('lastName'); ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label> Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="userName" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('usernName'); ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="passWord" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('passWord'); ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>UserType</label>
    <input type="text" name="userType" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The issue was not on functions (model/controller) at all.
btw, Thanks for everyone who shared idea, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I just want to say thank you for sharing your answer after figuring it out yourself :)

Comment: yeah thank you as well. what a nice community here

Answer (score 0):

print your query inside model function and see what is the error

```
public function add_user($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('tblaccount', $data);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Should i enter exact code? echo $this->db->last_query()?

Comment: yes execute the code, and check the response on browser

Comment: i just did sir. nothing happend. where should i check the respond? what do you meant by response on browser? should i use developer's tool?

Comment: print_r($data);exit(); before $this->db->insert('tblaccount', $data); to check whether you are getting data or not. In your browser. not in developer tool

Comment: Does your data columns and table columns exactly same?

Comment: Yes they are the same, except for the table's id, but its a primary key (auto-increment)

Comment: Its solved already sir. Thanks for sharing idea :)